# how to find the siblings of parent using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

in my case am having a two html elements covered by a another element(grand parent) like this

```
 <div class="tabs">
  <ul class="header">
    <li> <a> </a> </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="content show"> </div>
  </div>
```

here `tabs` is a grand parent and `header` and `show` are its child my problem is while clicking `<a>` which is a grand child of `header` need to remove a class `show` sibling of `header`

i used `closest()` it doesn't help's here my tried [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VkranthVivek/69z5B/40/)

```
$(this).closest('content').removeClass('show');
```

help me out

**EDIT**: (markup in jsfiddle)

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tabheader">
        <li class="active"><a href="#fragment-1"><span>FAQs</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Credit bundle</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-3"><span>Delivery & turnaround times</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-4"><span>Testimonials</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div id="fragment-1" class="tabed_contents show">adasdasd</div>
    <div id="fragment-2" class="tabed_contents">adasdasd</div>
    <div id="fragment-3" class="tabed_contents">adasdasd</div>
    <div id="fragment-4" class="tabed_contents">adasdasd</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Notice that you missed a `.` in `$(this).closest('content').removeClass('show');`

Comment: yea i missed now the mistake is fixed and my new problem is when remove Show class it remove all show class on same page how do i prevent it..? http://jsfiddle.net/VkranthVivek/69z5B/44/

Comment: $(this).parents().eq(1).siblings().removeClass('show');

Comment: Do you have more than one element with class `.show` inside each `div.tabs` ?

Comment: @Sergio No am having more than one div.tabs which having only one show class..

Comment: Then the first alternative Rory wrote should work: `$(this).closest('.tabs').find('.tabed_contents ').removeClass('show');`

Comment: @Sergio still the same problem :( http://jsfiddle.net/VkranthVivek/69z5B/48/

Comment: I don't get the problem... Check here http://jsfiddle.net/69z5B/49/ - what is not working?

Comment: @Sergio  Am having two tab navigation in a same page right.there im having `show` class the purpose of `show` class was while loading a page the first content of tab menu should be shown.now the problem is am having multiple tab menu in a same page while viewing first menu the `show` class for other menu also get removed.. :(

Comment: Aha... you mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/hwrK6/

Comment: @Sergio :) yea offcourse what you changed. :)

Comment: Ok, nice! please accept Rory's answer. I added that info there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you need to use the `.` prefix in your class selector. However, what you have is looking for the parent `.content` element, yet it is a sibling of a parent and hence will not be found.

Try this:

```
$(this).closest('.tabs').find('.tabed_contents').removeClass('show');
```

Alternatively, you could go to `.header` and find the sibling `.content`.

```
$(this).closest('.header').siblings('.tabed_contents').removeClass('show');
```

To not hide all the `.tabed_contents` use this:

```
$(this).closest('.tabs').find('.tabed_contents').hide();
```

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hwrK6/)

Comment: Okeis bruv, lemme upvote you bruv `:)` good to see you in long time!

Comment: I say +1. OP has another markup in jsfiddle, I just updated. Maybe `.tabed_contents` instead of content.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it removes all the show 'class' on the same page how do i prevent it.. http://jsfiddle.net/VkranthVivek/69z5B/44/

Comment: Added some things, hope its ok!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$( this ).parent().parent().siblings(".content").removeClass('show');
```